# How do I create folders inside Zip::OutputStream?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, zip

I want to create a Zip-file with **folders** or **directories** in it, using Ruby-on-Rails and Zip.

How do I create folders or directories inside Zip::OutputStream?

**What I currently have**

```
compressed_filestream = Zip::OutputStream.write_buffer do |zos|

  zos.put_next_entry "letter.odt"
  zos.write letter

  zos.put_next_entry "spreadsheet.ods"
  zos.write spreadsheet

  zos.put_next_entry "essay.odt"
  zos.write essay
end

compressed_filestream.rewind
send_data compressed_filestream.read, filename: "neuer_tn.zip"
```

This code produces a Zip-file and I can extract the three files from it, called "letter.odt", "spreadsheet.ods" and "essay.odt".

Now, I want that the first two files are inside a folder or inside a directory. When I extract the Zip-file, I should see a folder called "letter and spreadsheet", where two files are inside, and one file outside of it. How can I do that?

Is something like the following code possible?

```
compressed_filestream = Zip::OutputStream.write_buffer do |zos|

  zos.create_folder "letter and spreadsheet" do 
  
    zos.put_next_entry "letter.odt"
    zos.write letter

    zos.put_next_entry "spreadsheet.ods"
    zos.write spreadsheet

  end

  zos.put_next_entry "essay.odt"
  zos.write essay
end

compressed_filestream.rewind
send_data compressed_filestream.read, filename: "neuer_tn.zip"
```

Rails 6.0.3.4,
ruby 2.6.6p146 (2020-03-31 revision 67876) [x86_64-linux]

Comment: @dbugger Thank you very much! Please post it as an answer, so I can accept it. Or delete my question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's very straightforward, include the folder name in the `put_next_entry` call...

```
zos.put_next_entry "awesome_folder_here/letter.odt"
```

You can even go deeper...

```
zos.put_next_entry "awesome_folder_here/subfolder_too/letter.odt"
```

And the zip knows how to put it all together.